# Validate format of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing an Rails 4.1.4 web app and I need to validate that the users
input is correct. The input is time in this format 12:00 (HH:MM). I just need to check that there are first 2 integers before the : and two integers after. How can I do this in a validation? I rather not use a gem for this simple task. I think it could be done with a regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [validates_format_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_format_of):

```
validates_format_of :time, with: /\A\d{2}:\d{2}\z/
```

Comment: with this, you'll be able to write 10:99